# How to define string parameters in C++ header file - Bridged with Swift?

Tags: c++, xcode, string, macos, swift

I have a Xcode project with Swift and C++ (with bridging header), and I am trying to create a function in C++ with 2 string parameters, and returning an array of integers back to Swift:

**.cpp file:**

```
int* example(string one, string two)
{
    int test[3] = {7,2,3};
    return test;
}
```

**.h file:**

```
#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    int* example(string one, string two); //ERROR HERE

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I am getting this error (in the .h file):

> Unknown type name 'string'

I tried to include the string header file to the header, but then I get the error (I also had to add `std::` before the `string`):

**New function declaration:**

```
    int* example(std::string one, std::string two);
```

**Error (at the first `std::`)**

> Expected ')'

I am really losing my patience here, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have it in `extern "C"`?  There's nothing wrong with `int* example(std::string one, std::string two);` if you `#include <string>`, however you are returning a pointer to an array which won't exist after it has returned. You also possibly don't want to be taking those strings by value - read about by value vs reference vs pointer

Comment: I have it in extern "C" because of Swift - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0x6JbiphNS4 , wont work without it. Anyway, how else should I return an int array?

Comment: You can use `std::array` or `std::vector`. If you will want to push/pop/resize/clear/etc the array or if it's a lot of data use std::vector, if it's a hardcoded length and very small amount of data use std::array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use class types in extern "C" declaration. You can introduce the following trick:

header:

```
#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int* example(void *one, void *two);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

source: (.cpp assumed)

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
extern "C" {

    int* example(void *one, void *two)
    {
        string &a = *reinterpret_cast<string*>(one);
        string &b = *reinterpret_cast<string*>(two);
    ...
    }
}
```

You must pass strings by ptr.

Comment: I tryed to pass the string with: let aStr = UnsafeMutablePointer<String>.alloc(1)
        aStr.initialize(str) ,  but the string is empty in C++ ( no crash or error)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't handle swift. Can you cast a literal string  for testing?

Comment: Okay, I got the strings working. How could I return an vector of integers? I get that error in the header again, because of the vector type...

Comment: You can use the same strategy passing a the address of the pointer as argument (int * * pptr) then, you can fill the pointer with the address of the array: *pptr = (int * )malloc(value);