# Interact C ++ from Objective-C and Swift

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, objective-c++

I would like to use a C++ method in an Objective-C project, as well as in a Swift project.

I have a C++ class in a namespace. In Objective-C it is not. Do I need to use Objective C++?

I have another class which is written in C++. I would like to use these methods in a Swift project. Can I interact with C++ from Swift?

Comment: Yes you Swift can interact with C++, but you'll have to define the methods in the `extern "C"`. Heres an excelent tutorial on how to make it: [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0x6JbiphNS4) Also, if you'll need to pass Strings to C++, heres my question a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545404/how-to-define-string-parameters-in-c-header-file-bridged-with-swift

Comment: Modified the language a bit to be clearer, but there is still some uncertainty about the namespace part. You may want to add some more information about that to make sure you get the right answers for your question.